# How to change Matlab default data precision other than 'vpa'?

Tags: matlab, precision, symbolic-math

I would like to perform a matrix division on two large matrices, A \ b, (e.g., 1000-by-1000 and 1000-by-1). I always get a warning from this operation:
**Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = XXX**

I think the problem is mainly because some elements in A and b have more than 16 digits.

I tried using 'vpa' to increase the precision, but it is super slow for converting a large matrix and the data type is no longer 'double' which would cause some problems later in my algorithm.

Could you please tell me if there is any way to change Matlab default data precision other than using vpa?

(P.S. you might suggest me using Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm to tackle the problem, but I found only a very large damping parameter can remove this warning, which is not very ideal in my case)

Comment: I don't think there are more "native" options than `double` and `vpa`/ `symbolic`, and the latter do slow down computation compared to `double`. You can try this external toolbox, but it's also probably going to be slow: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class?s_tid=srchtitle

Comment: Increasing the number of digits used isn't going to solve your problem. The fundamental issue is that your equations are very nearly dependent ... you have an ill posed problem. You need to solve that issue first. What you are attempting to do is equivalent to trying to find the intersection point of two very nearly parallel lines. Numerically you might get an answer but the answer couldn't be trusted. You need to re-examine how you are going about solving your problem, and address the issue of why you have dependencies among your equations.

Comment: a "badly scaled" matrix has nothing to do with the number of digits. What is probably causing the problem is you have values in the matrix which are too separated (example, you have values extremely close to zero and values extremely close to the max value a `double` can hold).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'too many digits' in Matlab matrices. They are stored as 8 byte doubles. Your assumption about the problem is wrong.